# Integration by Simpson's Rule

Tags: c

One of my assignments was to create a c program that uses the Simpson's 1/3 rule to find the sum. I am running into issues that I am having trouble fixing. Can some one with more experience point me in the right direction?

In theory my code integrates y=ax^2+bx+c where the user selects values for a,b,c and then the user selects the upper and lower bounds [d,e]. Then the user selects the n value which splits up the area into more rectangles (the value that we will use in my class is 100, so the area is split into 100 rectangles). After which it runs through the Simpson's rule and prints out the sum.

```
//n is required number of iterations.

#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

double integral (int a,int b,int c,int d,int e,int n)

int main()
{
    double a, b, c, d, e, n;

    printf("Please select values for y=ax^2+bx+c");
    printf("Please select value for a");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Please select value for b");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("Please select value for c");
    scanf("%d", &c);
    printf("Please select value for the upper limit");
    scanf("%d", &d);
    printf("Please select value for the lower limit");
    scanf("%d", &e);
    printf("Please select the number of rectangles for the Simpson's Rule (Input 100)");
    scanf("%n", &n);

    int i;  
    double sum=0,length=(double)(d-e)/(n),ad,bd,cd,dd;

    ad=(double)a;
    bd=(double)b;
    cd=(double)c;
    dd=(double)d;
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        sum+=(ad*(dd*dd+2*dd*length*i+length*length*i*i)+bd*(dd+length*i)+cd)*length;
        printf("the value is = %d",sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think this

```
scanf("%e", &e);
```

should be that way?

The [`scanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) function takes a format specifier to match the scanned input with, in your case you want to store the values in a `double` variable, for which you need the `"%lf"` specifier, so all your `scanf()`'s should change to

```
scanf("%lf", &whateverDoubleVariableYouWantToStoreTheResultIn);
```

You don't need to cast from a variable of a given type to the same type, like here

```
dd=(double)d;
```

And also, you must know, that `scanf()` returns a value, you should not ignore it because your program will misbehave in case of bad input, you should check `scanf()` in a library manual or the C standard to understand better how to use it.

Comment: It shouldve been scanf("%d", &e); I was having trouble integrating the code in the post.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@iharob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29400127/2410359) fine advice:

1. Change `n` type

   ```
   // double a, b, c, d, e, n;
   double a, b, c, d, e;
   int n;
   ```
2. Adjust input code

   ```
   // and previous lines
   if (1 != scanf("%lf", &e))  // %d --> %lf
     Handle_InputError();
   printf("Please select the number of rectangles for the Simpson's ...
   if (1 != scanf("%d", &n)  // %n --> %d
     Handle_InputError();
   ```
3. Adjust output

   ```
   // printf("the value is = %d",sum);
   printf("the value is = %e",sum);  // or %f
   ```
4. Minor bits

   ```
   // int main()  
   int main(void) // or int main(int argc, char *argv[])

   // return sum;  returning a double here is odd
   return 0;
   ```